# Apache segfaults on Wordpress admin page

Tags: apache-2.2, php, wordpress, segmentation-fault

I can access the frontend of a new Wordpress setup without issue. I can also log in with a user account without issue. However, if I try to log in with an admin account I get a 500 error about 70-80% of the time.

If I do manage to get through to the WP dashboard, any page within the admin panel will cause the error only /sometimes/ - I can't find a set way to reproduce the error.

Apache's error log shows a segmentation fault for each of these 500 errors.

I started my investigation with Wordpress:

- Disabled all WP plugins
- Reset the theme to default
- Removed .htaccess and hit the php pages directly

The error sill intermittently occured.

I figured my next step should be to get a core dump of the Apache thread that died to see if there are any clues, but I can't get it to dump.

I'm running Debian 6.0.4 and have followed the instructions in `/usr/share/doc/apache2.2-common/README.backtrace`, which state:

> 1) Install the packages apache2-dbg libapr1-dbg libaprutil1-dbg gdb.
>
> 2) Add "CoreDumpDirectory /var/cache/apache2" to your apache
>   configuration.
>
> 3) Execute as root:
>           /etc/init.d/apache2 stop
>           ulimit -c unlimited
>           /etc/init.d/apache2 start
>
> 4) Do whatever it takes to reproduce the crash. There should now be
>   the file /var/cache/apache2/core .

Still, the core files aren't being dumped, and Apache's error log doesn't have `(core dumped)` in the segmentation fault lines.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue and I fixed it by upgrading the ssh php module with `sudo pecl install ssh2-0.13` on Ubuntu.

Answer (score -1):

Try to `chmod 777` that directory. If you put the dump into `/tmp` you may have more success as tmp is writable by everyone on the system. I had the same problem and doing this and running the commands in step 3 in sequence instead of all at once got me what I needed.